# Obtaining information about a process in Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, process

One can get information about a process according to its PID reading files in /proc/PID directory. Is there any library providing such information directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [libproc-dev](http://packages.debian.org/sid/libproc-dev)

And [here](http://matburt.net/?p=8) is a little example